# When was .on() introduced to jQuery?

Tags: jquery, livequery, jquery-1.3

I have a legacy code that uses the Live Query plugin extensively. This code uses jQuery 1.3.1. I need to replace the deprecated .livequery() with the modern .on() (http://api.jquery.com/on/), but I do not think .on() was available with jQuery 1.3.1. In which version of jQuery was was .on() incorporated for the first time? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the top right side of the webpage you can see in which version it was added. The .on() function was added in 1.7 version.

Comment: I tried to find it in the heading with the black background, and I did not pay attention to the heading with the blue background, which is where they put it. This is exactly what I needed to know. Thank you.